# Merge entities which have the same children

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

The C# code below, using LINQ to Entities, aims to merge all `Class` entities which have the same `SubjectId` and the same `Students`.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var counter = 0;

using (var ctx = new Ctx()) 
{
  var allClasses = ctx.Classes.Where(o => o.SubjectId > 0).OrderBy(o => o.Id).ToList();
  foreach (var c in allClasses)
    ctx.LoadProperty(c, o => o.Students);

  // For each class...
  for (var i = 0; i < allClasses.Count; i++) 
  {
      var c = allClasses[i];
      var duplicates = allClasses
             .Where(o => o.SubjectId == c.SubjectId && o.Id != c.Id &&
                         o.Students.OrderBy(s => s.Id).Select(s => s.Id)
                              .SequenceEqual(c.Students.OrderBy(s => s.Id)
                                                  .Select(s => s.Id)))
             .ToList();

      // Does it have any duplicates?
      if (duplicates.Count == 0) 
          continue;

      ctx.LoadProperty(c, o => o.PeriodsTimetable);
      // For each duplicate...
      for (var j = 0; j < duplicates.Count; j++) 
      {
          var d = duplicates[j];
          // If the duplicate class has a timetable slot that's not also allocated to 
          // the class we are keeping, then allocate it (otherwise MySql will delete it).
          ctx.LoadProperty(d, o => o.PeriodsTimetable);
          var dt = d.PeriodsTimetable.ToList();
          for (var k = 0; k < dt.Count; k++) 
          {
              var dtp = dt[k];
              var tpIsDuplicate = false;
              foreach (var ctp in c.PeriodsTimetable) 
              {
                  if (dtp.TeacherId == ctp.TeacherId && 
                      dtp.PeriodTime == ctp.PeriodTime) 
                  {
                      tpIsDuplicate = true;
                  }
              }

              if (!tpIsDuplicate) 
                  dtp.ClassId = c.Id;
      }

      // Now update all other entities which reference the duplicate to instead      
      // reference the class we are keeping.
      var dPeriods = ctx.Periods.Where(o => o.ClassId == d.Id).ToList();
      for (var k = 0; k < dPeriods.Count; k++) 
          dPeriods[k].ClassId = c.Id;

      var dAssessments = ctx.Assessments.Where(o => o.ClassId == d.Id).ToList();
      for (var k = 0; k < dAssessments.Count; k++) 
          dAssessments[k].ClassId = c.Id;

      var dSeatingPlans = ctx.SeatingPlans.Where(o => o.ClassId == d.Id).ToList();
      for (var k = 0; k < dSeatingPlans.Count; k++) 
          dSeatingPlans[k].ClassId = c.Id;

      var dMerits = ctx.Merits.Where(o => o.ClassId == d.Id).ToList();
      for (var k = 0; k < dMerits.Count; k++) 
          dMerits[k].ClassId = c.Id;

      sb.Append(d.LongName).Append(" merged with ").Append(c.LongName).Append(".<br />");
      // Finally, delete the duplicate
      ctx.Classes.DeleteObject(d);
      allClasses.Remove(d);
      counter++;
    }
  }
  ctx.SaveChanges();
  lblOutput.Text = "<b>Merged " + counter + " duplicate classes.</b><br /><br />" + sb.ToString();
}
```

For an idea of scale, there are about 1600 classes with 30 students each, and `counter` comes out at just over 300.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is *very* difficult to read.  (To give you an idea of *how* difficult it is, I've been looking at this for the past 2 hours so far)

- You are using traditional `for` loops when you instead should be using `foreach` loops.
- Your "loop variables" are poorly named.  Look toward the end of the code.  What is a `c`?  What is a `d`?  Leave the shorter names within smaller lambdas, index varialbes and possibly single instances of "utility" objects (e.g., `StringBuilder` or `Regex`).
- You are trying too hard to write everything within a single line.  `for` loops, `if` conditions, large queries... all of them should span multiple lines.  With perhaps an exception to the `if (duplicates.Count == 0) continue;` line.  I'd be okay with that *but* you should try to keep those to a minimum (it might be possible that you could code it so that line is not needed).
- You have a long chain of `Append()`s to the string builder when you really should use a single call to `AppendFormat()`.
- There are some snippets of your code which would work better either as a separate method or a LINQ query.  *Use it.*
- LINQ to Entities should have made associations between your objects so your joins could be replaced by using the navigation properties.  If you don't have those set up, you should.
- You also have some useless comments.  `// For each class...`  Do we really need a comment to tell us that?  Well, maybe since we were using `for` loops but that should have been avoided in the first place.

You have a lot of performance issues too.

- You are calling `ToList()` on *every* query when you are simply just enumerating over it most of the time.
- You have a lot of repeated loops on the same collection too.  You should be able to do a lot within a single loop.
- Your query for finding duplicates will be a huge hit.  I don't have much to say on it right now but it's already making this `O(n^2)`.
- I have a feeling that you don't need the calls to `LoadProperty()`.  From what I can tell, the majority of your code is filling in data manually when you probably don't need to.  Unfortunately I don't know the entity framework enough to know better (though I am looking into it right now).

Applying what I've explained to your code, I'd start with this (hopefully I didn't break anything).

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var counter = 0;
using (var ctx = new SchoolModel())
{
    var allClasses = ctx.Classes
        .Where(o => o.SubjectId > 0)
        .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
        .ToList(); 

    foreach (var aClass in allClasses)
    {
        ctx.LoadProperty(aClass, o => o.Students);

        // a properly crafted query could remove this completely and not use LINQ to Objects
        var students = new HashSet<int>(aClass.Students.Select(s => s.Id));
        var dupClasses = allClasses
            .Where(o => o.SubjectId == aClass.SubjectId
                     && o.Id != aClass.Id
                     && students.SetEquals(o.Students.Select(s => s.Id)))
            .ToList();

        if (dupClasses.Count == 0) continue;

        ctx.LoadProperty(aClass, o => o.PeriodsTimetable);

        foreach (var dupClass in dupClasses)
        {
            // If the duplicate class has a timetable slot that's not also allocated to the
            // class we are keeping, then allocate it (otherwise MySql will delete it).
            ctx.LoadProperty(dupClass, o => o.PeriodsTimetable);

            foreach (var dupTimetable in dupClass.PeriodsTimetable)
            {
                var isDuplicate = aClass.PeriodsTimetable
                    .Any(ctp => dupTimetable.TeacherId == ctp.TeacherId
                             && dupTimetable.PeriodTime == ctp.PeriodTime);
                if (!isDuplicate)
                    dupTimetable.ClassId = aClass.Id;
            }

            // Now update all other entities which reference the duplicate to instead reference
            // the class we are keeping.
            foreach (var dupPeriod in dupClass.Periods)
                dupPeriod.ClassId = aClass.Id;
            foreach (var dupAssessment in dupClass.Assessments)
                dupAssessment.ClassId = aClass.Id;
            foreach (var dupSeatingPlan in dupClass.SeatingPlans)
                dupSeatingPlan.ClassId = aClass.Id;
            foreach (var dupMerit in dupClass.Merits)
                dupMerit.ClassId = aClass.Id;

            sb.AppendFormat("{0} merged with {1}.<br />", dupClass.LongName, aClass.LongName);

            // Finally, delete the duplicate
            ctx.Classes.DeleteObject(dupClass);

            // not sure this is really needed
            allClasses.Remove(dupClass);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    Output = "<b>Merged " + counter + " duplicate classes.</b><br /><br />" + sb.ToString();
}
```

That's my initial analysis so far.  I'll update some more once I've gained understanding on what you are doing.  As I've said, it is *very* difficult to read.  I'll probably offer more improvements once I've had a chance to look at it more.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. I like some of your ideas and will implement them. In response to a few of your points: (1) The compiler won't let me use foreach because the enumerable collection is modified in each case (though I'm not sure how in some cases), (2) The variable names made sense to me, e.g. c=class, d=duplicate, and I'm working on this project alone, but I accept that they are unclear - sorry, (3) Without `ToList()` when looping through, for example, `PeriodsTimetable`, an error is thrown about updating references. Again I'm afraid I don't understand why.

Comment: For points (1) and (3), you probably would be able to use `AsEnumerable()` instead of calling `ToList()`.  It would seem that updating objects when enumerating through an entity set is not possible.  Using `AsEnumerable()` would force using LINQ to Objects and hopefully allow this to work without being forced to throw them into a list.

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid. The type is already `IEnumerable<EntityName>` so AsEnumerable() has no effect. I very much like your `HashSet<int>`, `PeriodsTimetable.Any` and `sb.AppendFormat` improvements and am testing them now. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, after having thought about it, I could now see why that would cause problems.  We're changing the FK so it would alter the collection indirectly since the changes are tracked.  I'm still exploring what would be the better way to handle this.  I _think_ you might be able to do something like this instead (looking at the period updates): `dupPeriod.Class = aClass;` instead of changing the id's, it will all be handled for you (and no need to use `ToList()`).  I hope I just didn't butcher that explanation.  :)

Comment: I have a few remarks because small parts of the code go back to my answer on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780455/detect-entities-which-have-the-same-children/7780935#7780935 . 1) `LoadProperty` (explicite loading) is ugly ideed and the code is a typical case where one would tend to use `Include` (eager loading). However, it has serious performance problems (see James' comment to my answer about the perf. gain with explicite loading). 2) You cannot move `LoadProperty(aClass, o => o.Students)` into the main loop because the inner query for `dupClasses` will fetch classes...

Comment: ...which haven't been met yet in the main loop. Therefore the `Students` collection is empty or `null`. So the result would be wrong or the code will crash. Hence `LoadProperty` must be in that separate loop before. 3) I recommended to do the identification for duplicates in memory with LINQ to Objects because LINQ to Entities has many limitations and to find a LINQ query which is translatable into SQL might be hard (see exception in James' question in the SO link above). With your other points I agree, and learning that `HashSet` has a `SetEquals` method was worth alone the look here :)

Comment: @Slauma: Thank you for reviewing my review to a Code Review review.  :)  I'm sure James did the right thing with that `LoadProperty`.  I knew L2E has issues with some complex queries, thanks for pointing that out.  I was a bit overambitious with some of the changes in my example though.